# Create a click on Contact to call MS Outlook 2010 Add-In with MS Visual Studio 2013

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio-2013, outlook-addin, outlook-2010

I would like implement outlook 2010 Add-In that will help to call to a outlook contact by my local application.

Scenario:

1. Need a "call to dial" application that help to call a number of outlook contact.
2. When click on outlook contact, then Add-In must be get called & divert that call to my local application.

e.g. MS Lync Add-In works with Outlook contacts to call a selected contact's number.

I have seen many video & studied many tutorial and but didnt get info that how to implement desired scenario.

I used below approaches

With Add-In Express:
1. MS Visual Studio 2013-> Visual C#-> Office-> Office Add-In.

With VSTO:
2. MS Visual Studio 2013-> Other Project Type-> Extensibility->ADX Add->In

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can add custom controls on the ribbon and add context menu items for contacts allowing users to make a call. VSTO provides two main ways for customizing the UI:

- [Walkthrough: Creating a Custom Tab by Using the Ribbon Designer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386104.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)
- [Walkthrough: Creating a Custom Tab by Using Ribbon XML](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa942955.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

You may find the [Extending the User Interface in Outlook 2010](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee692172(v=office.14).aspx) article helpful.

The Fluent UI (aka Ribbon UI) is described in depth in the following series of articles:

- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 1 of 3)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338202(v=office.12).aspx)
- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 2 of 3)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338199(v=office.12).aspx)
- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 3 of 3)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa722523(v=office.12).aspx)

Finally, instead of developing Outlook add-in you may consider integrating your existing application with Office. See [Integrating IM applications with Office](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj900715.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) for more information.

It doesn't matter whether VSTO or Add-in Express is used. The Outlook extensibility model is the same for all kind of add-ins.

Comment: Thanks for the information. I have gone through the article "Integrating IM applications with Office ". I am not c# developer so don't how to implement it. Could you please share any example or sample code for the same?